# Unable to inject IRepository<TEntity> due to "no implicit reference conversion"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, type-conversion, aspnetboilerplate, conventions

Started off and trying to get familiar with the ASP.NET Boilerplate template for .NET Core.

Everything was going smoothly until I needed to inject an `IRepository` with a generic `Entity` into a class constructor.

In the `DepartmentManager` class, when I tried to create a private read-only field to inject into the constructor, I get the IntelliSense error that:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from Department to
>   Abp.Domain.Entities.IEntity The Type Department cannot be used
>   as type parameter TEntity in the generic type or method
>   'IRepository, primary key'

I have tried to research to see if I could find similar problems online with some solutions, but to no avail.

Below is a simple code to illustrate the challenge.

```
// Class 
public class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

// IDepartment Manager
public interface IDepartmentManager
{
    Task<Department> CreateDepartment(Department entity);
    Task Update(Department entity);
    Task Delete(long id);
    Task<IEnumerable<Department>> GetAll();
}

// Department Manager    
private readonly IRepository<Department, long> _departmentRepo;
public DepartmentManager(IRepository<Department, long> departmentRepo)
{
    _departmentRepo = departmentRepo
}
```

Any help is well appreciated on what I am not doing right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Department` implement `Entity<long>` or `IEntity<long>` to use its repository.

```cs
public class Department : Entity<long>
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

#### References

- Entities: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entities
- Repositories: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories